# Building a car SatNav from a RPi

Tags: pi-zero, gps, cars, pi-3a+

My Garmin car GPS died, and im thinking about building my own. I saw that there are a couple pretty good navigation softwares out there, and I want to use one of them, with OSM maps and a 7" touch screen. I had a couple questions :

- Is there any difference in terms of performance and praticality between a USB GPS module and a GPIO module ?
- Would a PI-Zero (alternatively, a PI3A+) be powerful enough to run maps and guiding software smoothly ? I am worried about RAM quantity and CPU power.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you're looking for a Pi as a SatNav system instead of a GPS?

Comment: @Dirk yes exactly ! I want to turn a PI into a DIY navigation system for my car

Comment: USB GPS module is more flexible if you just want to use it, because it can be plugged into any computer .... if you want to experiment with it at a microcontroller level, then a GPIO module would be more useful ... look for a GPS module that can use both interfaces

Comment: about the performance of the system ... if the Raspberry Pi is laggy, then you can simply port the project to another device ... after all, you are running the application on a linux computer, so it should be fairly simple to move to another, more powerful linux computer

Comment: @jsotola I didnt think of it that way, you are right : a PI can definitively find an other purpose if it cant do that job correctly...